# Would you tell me which one you prefer? such as or such

Tags: adverbs

> A picture **such as** this
>
> **Such** a picture **as** this

Which of the rephrases are more polished or influence?

Or, which one would you rather?

Comment: Either could be OK. It would depend on the larger context and what one is trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd prefer

> A picture such as this

I don't like the second

> Such a picture as this

It's not that there's anything technically wrong with it, it just doesn't sound fluid to me. My brain would likely re-hear what they said, just to make sure I understood correctly what they said.

Another alternative would be

> A picture like this one, ...

Comment: But you could say "Such a picture as this I would never go see". It emphasizes the picture as the topic.

Comment: @user3169 - Yes, I suppose you _could_ say that – but it doesn't sound like very natural conversational English.